# Javascript event register can not be remembered under Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, html

I meet a strange question about javascript event register. Test file "test.html" is:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value='button' />
<script>
alert('here');
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {alert('here1');}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I open a web browser with a blank page, such as "about:blank", then go to "test.html", then hit Web browser "Go back" button to "blank" page, then hit "Go Foward" back to "test.html" again.

1. IE and Firefox:

After "Go back" and "Go Forward", alter('here') will not show, but the button can work fine. (I think this is ok.)

2. Chrome (PC):

After "Go back" and "Go Forward", alter('here') will show, and the button can work fine.

3. Android Browser:

After "Go back" and "Go Forward", alter('here') will not show, and the button can NOT work.

(I use default Internet browser in a samsung galaxy, the browser agent information is "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; .... /AppleWebKit .../ Mobile Safari/")

If I use:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value='button' onclick="..."  />
```

the button can work under Android web browser.

Why the javascript event register can be remembered (like IE, FF, Chrome) under Android web browser? any ideas?

Did I miss something? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the .addEventListener().

HTML:

```
<!-- Using a button -->
<input type="button" id="btn-id" />

<!-- Using a form -->
<form id="form-id">
    <input type="button" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
// just a click event
document.getElementById('#btn-id')

    .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do stuff
    });

// or using a form submit
document.getElementById('#form-id')

    .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do stuff
    });
```

Hope it helps